# pulling data in msql to tableview

Tags: swift

I want to print the data I have taken from Mssql to tableview. But I can't print this data to tableview. The data I want to print is a mail address, a string value. I am using mssql database. How can I print the data I have taken from msql to tableview?

```
class MakaleController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var makaleTable: UITableView!
    var stringvalue: [String] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
        let client = SQLClient.sharedInstance()!
                         client.connect("asd", username: "asd", password: "asd", database: "asd") { success in
                         client.execute("SELECT Email FROM and", completion: { (_ results: ([Any]?)) in
                          for table in results as! [[[String:AnyObject]]] {
                              for row in table {
                                  for (columnName, value) in row {
                                           print(value)
                                          if let intVal = value as? Int {
                                               self.stringvalue.append(String(intVal))
                                            DispatchQueue.main.async { self.makaleTable.reloadData() }}} }}
                          client.disconnect()
                      })
                  }
    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return stringvalue.count
        }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {         
       let cell:UITableViewCell = self.makaleTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "makalecell") as! UITableViewCell
            cell.textLabel?.text = self.stringvalue[indexPath.row]
                    return cell
        }
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about where the problem is (data grab, data parse, cell render, etc.). Does `print(value)` successfully print the correct value?

Comment: It prints the data correctly.

Comment: database table type : nvarchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check that you're successfully casting the raw value to `Int` (which is why I added the second print statement) and then reload the table after all of the loops (not from within them as you were doing):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let client = SQLClient.sharedInstance()!

    client.connect("asd", username: "asd", password: "asd", database: "asd") { success in

        client.execute("SELECT Email FROM and", completion: { (_ results: ([Any]?)) in

            for table in results as! [[[String:AnyObject]]] {

                for row in table {

                    for (columnName, value) in row {

                        print(value) // prints correctly as NVARCHAR

                        if let val = value as? String { // edit: skip casting as Int, go straight to String
                            stringvalue.append(val)
                        }

                    }

                }

            }

            // reload table once after all loops are complete
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.makaleTable.reloadData()
            }

            client.disconnect()

        })

    }

}
```

Comment: The output works but does not print to tableview again.

Comment: I added a third print statement after reloading the table in my edit. What does that print?

Comment: output as follows: []

Comment: Then the remaining problem is that you aren't successfully converting `NVARCHAR` to `Int`. You print the `NVARCHAR` successfully but not the conversion to `Int` (and then to `String`).